# I want the variable to be accessed from anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, frontend

Here i want to access the variable "finalPrice " in another function, how can i achive this?

```
  function available(id){
    $.ajax({
        method:"GET",           
    }).done(function(data){        

     for(j=0; j<available_location.length; j++) {

            var finalPrice =available_location[j].price_details.final_price;
   };
});

function razorpay() {      
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://test4238.wickedride.com//api/cancelledEnquiries/add',
        type : 'GET',
        data : {

         },
        success: function(data){
              alert(finalPrice );
           }
    });
}
```

Comment: Move `var it-works` to outside the functions

Comment: Two things: firstly get rid of the hyphen in your variable names, secondly just most the variable declaration above the available function, so it's in the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `finalPrice` is scoped only to the `available` function since that's where it's declared (`var finalPrice`). In Javascript, if you want a variable to be accessable from all script scopes, move it outside the function, to the beginning of the script:

```
var finalPrice;

function available(id) {
    $.ajax({
          method:"GET",           
    }).done(function(data) {        
       for(j = 0; j < available_location.length; j++) {
           finalPrice = available_location[j].price_details.final_price;
       };
});

function razorpay() {      
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://test4238.wickedride.com//api/cancelledEnquiries/add',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
        },
        success: function(data){
           alert(finalPrice );
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define it outside the function and remove `var` from before final price in `available();`. Now it can be accessed by both functions.

```
 var finalPrice = 0;

 function available(id){
    $.ajax({
        method:"GET",           
    }).done(function(data){        

     for(j=0; j<available_location.length; j++) {

       finalPrice =available_location[j].price_details.final_price;
   };
});

function razorpay() {      
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://test4238.wickedride.com//api/cancelledEnquiries/add',
        type : 'GET',
        data : {

         },
        success: function(data){
              alert(finalPrice );
           }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second call require the first, use of callbacks. If it doesn't call boths, and wait for both answers before you perform the treatment which is to calculate the finalPrice and use it.

**It is bad to create a global variable** named `finalPrice` because I'm pretty sure you are running theses both request in **parralel**, which would result to uncertain behavior if `razorpay` resolve before `available`.

---

**First case example**

```
 function available(id, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
  }).done(function(data) {

    var finalPrice = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < available_location.length; j++) {
      finalPrice = available_location[j].price_details.final_price;
    }

    callback(finalPrice);
  });

  function razorpay(finalPrice) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://test4238.wickedride.com//api/cancelledEnquiries/add',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {

      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert(finalPrice);
      }
    });
  }

  available(id, function(finalPrice) {
    razorpay(finalPrice);
  });
```